# Browser close event instead of tab close event

Tags: javascript

I have a asp.net page in which I want to update database when browser close not tab close. I tried `window.onbeforeunload` event in JavaScript. It is working good enough when browser tab close but not giving desire result when Browser close in firefox only (not IE). What should I do in this circumstance?

Comment: Why would you want to make a difference between closing a tab and the entire browser? Do you mean that you want something to happen when all instances of your site/app are closed?

Comment: no, system considers 'tab close' and 'browser close'  differently. i want two different types of event handler in javascript.

Comment: You can't do that. There is no difference between closing the browser or closing a tab from JS's point of view.

Comment: thanks for reply, but javascript is working differently in tab close and entire browser close in firefox. in my project database is updated with tab close which is intended, but not updating the database in entire close in firefox. in opera both works fine. i need to solve this issue.

Comment: That's because when you close the browser it doesn't have time to complete the AJAX request to the server. Again, there's nothing you can do with JS; you have to rethink your strategy.

Comment: thankx, but Juhana it is working very well with Opera browser.

Comment: Yes, but it will never work reliably on other browsers. You can argue against that until the end of time but it won't change the fact.

Comment: it's impossible with javascript !!!

Because: javascript only apply with tab, where this have included. It can't apply with order tab of browser, When user close tab, javascript only call 1 function window.onbeforeunload and out, but function window.onbeforeunload is solution for close tab, close all can be attack if you wrote a plugin for browser or a program in client PC, plugin and program will be check process of browser is closed.